# Java client for WebApi

Tags: java, asp.net-web-api, soapui

I have a CRM WebApi RESTful Service which I am trying to hit from Java. I tried the below code to hit the service, I am getting the response as expected.

```
URL url = new URL("WebAppURL");
connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.connect();
```

But when I tried to hit the same URL from Soap UI, it throws 401 Unauthorised error. Is it working in Java because HttpURLConnection uses Windows Authentication by **default** and I didn't provide any authorisation header in Soap UI ?

Comment: What happens if you use curl command?

Comment: 401 is returning from trying to get to the SOAP endpoint. Try open it from the web-browser. Does the Soap endpoint required you to authenticate? Maybe a proxy or firewall may have monitor that URL.

Comment: use fiddler to intercept and inpect the http requests going out from httpurlconnection vs Soap UI and  compare the two

Comment: May be you can try this library - https://github.com/jwagenleitner/groovy-wslite

Answer (score 0):

It is probably something to do with missing header attribute(s).